# Rendering Freestyle strokes behind objects using alpha transparency

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency, freestyle

Is there any way to render Freestyle edges according to their real visibility on camera, by taking in consideration the alpha transparency maps of occluding objects, without compositing multiple render layers ?

There is scenarios where compositing RenderLayers cannot be done, because the occluding object surrounds the target (ex. particle field) or because of the scene complexity (too much objects, camera paths...).

In the following example, green strokes aren't rendered when occluded by the plane with a red overlay that uses Z transparency and a circle texture as alpha.

[image: freestyle alpha visibility]

Comment: This is a known limitation/issue.. http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Freestyle#Known_Limitations_and_issues

Comment: how about rendering them in different layers?

Comment: @BlendingJake Excellent idea!

Comment: I have bad english knowledge- could you explain, what do you exactly want to do? Maybe I can help...

Comment: We want to be able to show Freestyle lines on an object behind a face with a transparent material.

Comment: Is it render or game?

Comment: You might try to find some settings in render options- there should be options about transparency, I think...

Comment: Cycles or BI, preferably Cycles

Comment: @BlendingJake It's usually possible to organize things in different layers and composite the result, but the question is about doing it when this scenario is not possible. (cf. 2nd paragraph).

Comment: @AdriansNetlis I ask if there is a way for  Freestyle to consider the transparency of an occluding object during its process of edge selection. As it is relative to the Freestyle integration, it may be relative to Render, Game or Cycle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in the current implementation of Freestyle.

[Blender 2.79, Freestyle Known Limitations](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/introduction.html#known-limitations)

> Transparent faces are treated as opaque faces.

[@gandalf3 / Blender 2.6](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15738/select-freestyle-strokes-behind-objects-using-alpha-transparency?noredirect=1#comment22172_15738)